# Sql unequal data sets in a access-table

Tags: sql, ms-access, dataset

I'm working since two weeks on a VBA-Application in Access 2016. For this I need to purge a Table on inconsistent data sets. To find out which Datasets are inconsistent, I need a SQL-query. So my Table looks like this:

```
ID        Description      User           Comment              Date

1         Example1         sht3454        This is a comment     10/17/2017
1         Example2         sht3454        This also             10/15/2017
2         Example3         hdjfur198      ;)                    10/11/2017
```

I have to find out which Datasets are inconsistent, in my Example the Datasets with the ID 1 because they have a different Description.
The Tablefield ID is in this example no primary key.
I thought about something like

`SELECT Count(ID), Description From DB_Data  group by ID,Description having (count(ID) > 1)`

but it is not the solution of my Problem.
Do someone of you have an idea for this?

Comment: Not sure if that's exactly what you want, but try `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Id), Description FROM DB_Data GROUP BY Id, Description HAVING (COUNT(Id) > 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select dd.*
from db_data dd
where exists (select 1
              from db_data dd2
              where dd2.id = dd.id and dd2.description = dd.description and
                    dd2.user <> dd.user
             ) or
       exists (select 1
              from db_data dd2
              where dd2.description = dd.description and dd2.user <> dd.user and
                    dd2.id <> dd.id
             ) or
       exists (select 1
              from db_data dd2
              where dd2.user = dd.user and dd2.id = dd.id and
                    dd2.description <> dd.description
             ) ;
```

This assumes that if two of the columns -- `id`, `description`, `user` -- are the same, then the other should be the same as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, the only inconsistency is that some records share their ID. You can those id-s with this query:

```
SELECT id FROM DB_Data GROUP BY id HAVING 1 < COUNT(id)
```

Moreover, you can select the related records if you use the previous query as a subquery:

```
SELECT DB_Data.*
FROM DB_Data 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM DB_Data GROUP BY id HAVING 1 < COUNT(id)) inconsistent
    ON (example.id = inconsistent.id)
```

Are there any other rules for inconsistent records?

Comment: Yes also the user could be different, so ID,Description and User are head data and comment, date are foot data. So I want to get all Datasets in which the Head Data is different.

Comment: @Stefan . . . You should add this information to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @Gordon . . . Sorry for that, this is my first time I am using a forum and asking questions. Next time I think of it.